# Initializing an object with a pattern in a concise way

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

I'm relatively new to Typescript (and Javascript), and have been messing around with classes. I'm trying to find a concise way to create an object that will be filled with similar entries while also keeping type safety.

Here is the code I've written:

```
let testFixture: Fixture = (() => {
  let stringPrefix = 'TEST BaseEventDTO';
  let result = {}; // The object to become a "Fixture".

  ['id', 'name', 'location'].forEach(element => {
    result[`${element}`] = generateId(`${stringPrefix} ${element}`);
  });

  return result;
})();
```

In this code, Fixtures have the required string fields `id`, `name`,  and `location`. Furthermore, I want all of them to have the stringPrefix before the name of the field, as shown in the foreach. I'm trying to create an object without typing the same stuff more than once, like the prefix or field names. The result, though, is an warning from VSCode that `Type {} is missing the following properties of Type 'Fixture': 'id', 'name', and 'location'`.

Is there a conventional way (or just working way) to go about this?

Also, to clarify, I'm writing this with an anonymous function to make the `stringPrefix` variable local.

EDIT: changing `return result;` to `return <Fixture>result;` fixed the error. But I'm leaving this in-case of my solution being a pitfall, or if there is another, better way to do this.

And for further clarification, result should, at the end, be equivalent to this:

```
let result = {
    id: generateID(`${stringPrefix} id`),
    name: generateID(`${stringPrefix} name`),
    location: generateID(`${stringPrefix} location`)
}
```

which would then be casted to a 'Fixture' type.

Comment: please add how the result should look like. what is `generateId` doing?

Comment: I've edited my question with more information. Is it sufficient?

Comment: generateID takes the given string and outputs a unique string that is encoded for database purposes.

Comment: You've confused more than clarified with this: _to clarify, I'm writing this with an anonymous function to make the stringPrefix variable local._ You've used an arrow function inside an IFEE, which is completely unnecessary. You've also overcomplicated your code with the string literal syntax, which is not necessary. Use the var names and simple concatenation.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm unsure about what you mean. The arrow function is the IFEE, as far as I can tell. There are just parenthesis around the arrow function. As for the literal syntax, I think it's opinion. This is more readable to me than concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll always have to cast and you've got two options

**Casting the initial variable**

```
const keys: Array<keyof Fixture> = ['id', 'name', 'location'];

let testFixture: Fixture = (() => {
  let stringPrefix = 'TEST BaseEventDTO';
  let result = {} as Fixture

  keys.forEach(element => {
    result[element] = generateId(`${stringPrefix} ${element}`);
  });

  return result;
})();
```

**Casting the return statement**

```
const keys: Array<keyof Fixture> = ['id', 'name', 'location'];

let testFixture: Fixture = (() => {
  let stringPrefix = 'TEST BaseEventDTO';
  let result: Partial<Fixture> = {}

  keys.forEach(element => {
    result[element] = generateId(`${stringPrefix} ${element}`);
  });

  return result as Fixture;
})();
```